# Xpages MobileControls and Categorized View

Tags: xpages

I have downloaded the Xpages mobile Controls from Openntf
and had a problem with the categorized view

I've used the ViewWithCategoriesAndDocument example to show a View with one Category this works fine.

But how do I use a View with multiple Categories?

has someone a Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using 853 and Upgrade Pack 1 that'll give you the Extlib controls along with the new Mobile controls? 

If so, use a Data View in a Mobile Page control. There you can add the multiple categories along with a summary and the mobile theme will take care of the rest.

```
            <xe:dataView id="dataView2" pageName="#p03"
             openDocAsReadonly="true">
            <xe:this.data>
                <xp:dominoView var="dominoView1" viewName="yourMultiCategorizedView" expandLevel="1"></xp:dominoView>
            </xe:this.data>
            <xe:this.summaryColumn>
                <xe:viewSummaryColumn columnName="Topic"></xe:viewSummaryColumn>
            </xe:this.summaryColumn>
            <xe:this.categoryColumn>
                <xe:viewCategoryColumn columnName="parentCategory"></xe:viewCategoryColumn>
            <xe:viewCategoryColumn columnName="subCategory"></xe:viewCategoryColumn></xe:this.categoryColumn>
        </xe:dataView>
```

Note in the above snippet that expandLevel="1" - this will collapse all the categorized views and make each category and subcategory selectable to expand those rows.

Comment: Ah Thanks I have tryed the "normal" Mobile Controls not from the Exlib
but with the exlib all works fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that expandLevel="1" doesn't always work right.  See
https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1LO58079
I wasted almost a day trying to get this one to work before I found out.